# undefined method `model_name' in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, render

While rendering xml for an object, I am getting the error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for OrderResponse:Class):

OrderResponse.rb

```
class OrderResponse
   include ActiveModel::Serialization

   attr_accessor :payload
end
```

In controller

```
def create
  @order_response = OrderResponse.new
  @order_response.payload = 12345

  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml { render :xml => @order_response }
  end
end
```

I found other questions with similar titles while searching, according to that i modified 'respond_to' with 'respond_with' which inturns throws an error

> undefinedMethod 'model_name' in OrderResponse

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to this somewhere on stackoverflow and wish I could credit the source... This is my interpretation of it.

In Rails 3, if you have a resource listed in your routes which has a model .rb file but no active record table behind it, then you'll see this kind of error. This appeared for me as a form_for trying to reference a :controller and :action in this model. Perhaps it is related to Rails attempting to process associations for the model or something similar. Either way, this is new for me since I upgraded an application from Rails 2.3.8.

For me, the appears as:

> undefined method `model_name' for SomeModel:Class

To fix it, at the top of the affected class add:

```
extend ActiveModel::Naming
include ActiveModel::Conversion
def persisted?
  false
end
```

This has worked for me on two models like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try defining a class method by that name, which returns the name of the class:

```
def self.model_name; 'OrderResponse'; end
```

Comment: After adding this, error gone away. But the xml is not rendered for the OrderResponse object

Answer (score 0):

try including `ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Module` where model_name is defined [ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Module](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Module/model_name)